# gitlab ci - You don't have permission to access the resource

Tags: permissions, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have developed an angular application, checked in the source codes to gitlab, which trigger the gitlab ci. The job is successful. In the job artifact page, I saw the following folders structure:  **workspace/public**.   Inside the public folder, I have the necessary html, javascript, etc.

I try to access using http://xxx.gitlab.io/index.html or even https://xxx.gitlab.io/index.html   (where xxx is my gitlab username). I keep getting the below

```
401
You don't have permission to access the resource.
The resource that you are attempting to access is protected and you don't have the necessary permissions to view it.
```

This implies that my url is correct, just that I dont have the permission.
What kind of permission is it referring to. Am i missing something in my steps?

Comment: I know from your question that you didn't make this particular mistake.  However, for those who found this question who made the same mistake as me.. the directory you add to artifacts has to be called `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to find the answer myself.
In the Job Artifacts page, the public folder should be at the root, not subfolder.
Once we can do that, under the Settings->Pages, u can see a box appear with the heading "Access Pages", with a link to your deployed website.

Comment: Thanks. But i cannot currently, cos i think need 2 days to mark my own answer

Answer (score 3):

Seems there can be a few reasons for a dreaded 401.  Just in case it can be helpful, I had the exact same 'symptoms'.  Job successful and could browse the artifacts.   The problem was the job name in the .gitlab-ci.yml was not named 'pages'.

Comment: I had this issue because I tried to name my job `pages_prod` and `pages_staging` but indeed only `pages` works for gitlab pages, other job names must be used for external deployment only (eg. AWS, Netlify, etc.)